# how to iterate and extract data from a list in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

How do i extract  elements from a list, only if the list contains specific intial elements

Here is the list data = [10, **16, 2**, 45, 52,12,0,0,2,0,54,85,23,15,48,78,45, 16,16 ,0,4, **16, 3**,  16, 2,0,....]

Example data:-

```
1)   [10,16,2,45,52,12,0,0,2,0,78,45,16,16,0,4,16,3,16,2,0,....] (upto 200bytes)
2)   [16,2,24,14,45,25,87,89,23,0,0,5,10,16,0,4,16,3,16,2,0,....]
3)   [11,12,24,14,45,25, 16,2, 121,45,0,10,16,0,4,16,3,16,2,0,....]
```

First i have to search for elements ***16,2*** and extract all the elements after ***16,2*** till it finds the elements ***16, 3*** and discard every repeating frame after that

Depending upon the data stream the initial bytes can be either in starting of the list or could start anywhere in the stream

Comment: `lst = data[data.index(16.2)+1:data.index(16.3)]`?...

Comment: @Delgan: I'm pretty sure `16` and `2` are different elements.

Comment: Oh yeah, that makes much more sense, thank you. x)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be fairly efficient, although a bit verbose

```
from itertools import islice

def n_grams(a, n):
    z = (islice(a, i, None) for i in range(n))
    return zip(*z)
​
def filterStartStop(lst, start, stop):
    it = n_grams(lst, 3)
    for i in it:
        if i[0:2] == start:
            break
    for i in it:
        if i[1:3] == stop:
            break
        yield i[1]

a = range(10)
print(list(filterStartStop(a, (1,2), (7,8))))
>>[3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comparing to @Kasramvd solution.

```
a = range(10**5)
start = (100, 101)
stop = (12345,12346)
%timeit list(filterStartStop(a, start, stop))
%timeit list(extracter(a, start, stop))

b = list(filterStartStop(a, start, stop))
c =  list(extracter(a, start, stop))
print (all(i == j for i,j in zip(b,c)))

>>100 loops, best of 3: 6.18 ms per loop
>>100 loops, best of 3: 19.4 ms per loop
>>True
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `zip` function to create the pairs and get the index of start and end pair them use slicing to extract the expected elements :

```
>>> def extracter(lst,start,end):
...     pairs = zip(lst,lst[1:])
...     start_index = pairs.index(tuple(start))+2
...     end_index = pairs.index(tuple(end))
...     return lst[start_index:end_index]
...
```

Demo:

```
>>> lst = [10, 16,2, 45,52,12,0,0,2,0,78,45,16,16,0,4, 16,3, 16,2,0]
>>> extracter(lst,(16,2),(16,3))
[45, 52, 12, 0, 0, 2, 0, 78, 45, 16, 16, 0, 4]
```

Comment: just curious ... does it discards all the elements after the end index. Because i have the same data repeating 1000 times in a stream  and i need only one good data packet of the whole stream

Comment: @user2345 Yes, because `list.index()` method will returns the index of first occurrence of the item.

Answer (score 1):

I think that I've found a solution.

```
def findIn(l):
    foundBeginning=False
    foundEnding=False
    for i in range(len(l)):
        if l[i] == 16:
            if l[i+1] == 2:
                if foundBeginning == False and foundEnding == False:
                    begin = i+2
                    foundBeginning = True
            if l[i+1] == 3:
                if foundBeginning == True and foundEnding == False:
                    end = I
                    foundEnding = True
    return(l[begin:end])
```